# Issue while passing to variable

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to compare a variable value in where clause.
Variable has correct value but in where clause it is not working.

```
Declare var varchar (50)
Begin
For i in (select table_name from tmp_table)
Loop
Var := i.table_name
Insert into new_table
Select * from all_tab_name atn
Where atn.table in (var)
Endloop
End;
```

It is sample query my original query is more big but this is the point where i have problem
It works if i hard code one table name but it is not working in loop if i either pass variable or assign directly i.table_name

Thanks in advance for help !

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? We can't help you unless you tell us what isn't working.

Comment: Please post the exact error message you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Several things jump out right off the bat, but there are probably many more mistakes you will find after you fix these.

Oracle recommends using varchar2 over varchar, but that is not a mistake. Then, you didn't add a semicolon ( `;` ) at the end of the declaration; that **is** a mistake and it is enough to make the compiler throw an error. Then, you are missing the semicolon in several other places. Is this the first time you write anything in PL/SQL? It certainly seems that way.

You use a loop variable `i` but you didn't declare it. That will throw another error. You said this is part of a longer code, and perhaps `i` is declared elsewhere - then you must edit your post to include **all** relevant parts of your code (if you are able to understand which those are ).

Then you assign to var the value i.table_name. What does that mean? i is already a table_name selected from tmp_table; do you mean i has a column named, coincidentally, table_name? Very unlikely. Did you mean to simply assign i to var?

I really can't understand anything from the next couple of lines of code, what were you trying to do there?

At the end, END LOOP is two words; if you write Endloop you will get another error.

I would recommend you take some time to learn PL/SQL before you start writing programs; what you posted demonstrates very, very little understanding of it. You won't save any time by just writing code you don't understand, without checking proper meaning and proper syntax, and posting it here for help. That's not how it works.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you are missing clause `into ...`

Comment: This answer might fail to actually be helpful to the OP as it is not clear how your suggestion might be applied to solve the problem. Please, illustarte your suggsetion, e.g. by showing the resulting correct code.